# Keycloak provider and user storage

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, wildfly, keycloak

I have a running java ee application and now i want to integrate keycloak as authentication server. The only thing i have troubles is the user storage. I want to have all the user data in my java application.

The problem now:
If the user registers on the keycloak frontend, my java application doesn´t know that the user has registered, so i cannot create a new entity. I found out that keycloak is able to load some custom modules (https://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/keycloak-server/html/providers.html) but i haven´t found any examples.

Is there any solution where keycloak notifys my java application when the user registered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same problem and I have resolved it using a filter. I just check if the principal exist and if not I insert it into my application DB:

`KeycloakSecurityContext ctx = (KeycloakSecurityContext)request.getAttribute(KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName());
 User userEntity = em.find(User.class, ctx.getToken().getSubject());
if (userEntity == null) {
   ....create user...
}`
 
You can also use an event listener ([keycloak events listener](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/keycloak-server/html/events.html)) as shown in [Example Event Listener that prints events to System.out](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/providers/event-listener-sysout), but for this exact use case that solution was easier and faster.

Comment: I ended up doing exactly the same. Sadly i still have to use the rest admin api to update the user roles.

Comment: It is possible to automatically use some roles. However, I do not see any problem into use the admin api. I also need it for System and Performance Testing

Comment: When does this filter method gets called?

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement a custom Authentication SPI (inside success() method you create user on your app), deployed it , and add it to the registration flow

Keycloak documentation : [Link](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi)