# How to integrate Keycloak user data into app db

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I have a spring boot application and a user column in my app db. The problem is now that my user informations are divided up at the spring boot db and the Keycloak db.

I found this older posts where there synced the data manually (redundant on both dbs), isn't there a best practice way, isn't this a standard usecase, I am wondering why there is no information about this?

[How to integrate or make use of KeyCloak user database in my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259607/how-to-integrate-or-make-use-of-keycloak-user-database-in-my-application)

[Keycloak provider and user storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053594/keycloak-provider-and-user-storage)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the standard use-case is you connect
**Keycloak** to your application's database, which contains users' information (keycloak is just a server to authenticate your users).

To be able to connect from Keycloak to your application's database, you need to implement new **Service provider interface** (User Storage SPI) as mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi).